# Netbeans Java Google App Engine local debug error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans

I am having trouble with my `Netbeans 8.0.2/Java 7/Google App Engine` environment and need some help.  Currently I am able to build and deploy to GAE cloud services without any problem.  But when I try to run or debug locally I get an error:

> “Missing value for property jvmargs”.

This happens with any project including the sample “guestbook” project.  I have double checked my path settings, my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, and re-installed Netbeans, Java 7 and the `GAE SDK (version 1.9.23)` multiple times all to no avail.

Has anyone seen this error before, or know how to repair it?

Comment: I don't KNOW if it'll help fix it, but I know that Netbeans had issues with threadsafe. is "<threadsafe>false</threadsafe>" in your appengine-web.xml?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: hmmm. You're building directly from Netbeans? doesn't it log some kind of log file? I know calling the SDK manually or with the App Engine launcher it always generates such a file. Did you try compiling and deploying using command line? (trying to see if the issue is with the SDK itself, or your Netbeans/profile/environment variables)

Comment: Actually I would love to use a command line SDK as the only thing I use Netbeans for is to build/deploy/run. It would be faster if I could do it from the command line.  Can you point me to documentation where I could learn to do that?

Comment: Normally when I do java work, I use maven to deploy (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven). If I code Python, I'll use the gcloud tool :)